# Is it anti-pattern to run asynchronous callbacks in catch blocks?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Is it an anti-pattern to run asynchronous callbacks in error catching like this?

```
await something()
   .catch(async (err) => {
      console.error(err);
      await otherStuff();
   });
```

Comment: It's an opinion if a pattern is good or bad.

Comment: I'd say the async callback is more of an anti-pattern.

Comment: It's imho an anti-pattern to mix `then`/`catch` with `async`/`await`/`try`/`catch`, unless the specific situation demands it (rare, but happens).

Comment: It's generally considered anti-pattern to use try/catch for business logic at all. It should only really be used for actual error handling. It's not entirely clear what you're doing there, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to have that whole expression there never reject - that is, to avoid the need for

```
try {
  await something()
   .catch(async (err) => {
      // ...
} catch(e) {
  // handle
}
```

Then what you're doing right now isn't safe if there's any chance of the `otherStuff` call rejecting. If `otherStuff` might reject, then you should make sure to catch possible errors *it* throws, eg

```
await something()
   .catch(async (err) => {
      console.error(err);
      await otherStuff();
   })
   .catch(handleOtherStuffErrors)
```

Though having an async function with only a single `await` isn't that useful - consider instead just returning the Promise:

```
await something()
   .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      return otherStuff();
   })
   .catch(handleOtherStuffErrors)
```

Chaining catches like that is *pretty odd*, but it's not impossible that that's what one's logic requires, so don't make a blanket statement about whether it's inherently bad.

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it is. In a promise you should return the promise instead of making the callback async and awaiting it.

I don't think it is since you can call `.then` behind the catch. Sometimes an throw just goes into a diffrent branch of operations but at the end its preference.

```
await something()
   .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      return otherStuff();
   }).then(res => {
  // work with data
});
```